# threading ignores KeyboardInterrupt exception

Tags: python, multithreading, events, exception, keyboardinterrupt

I'm running this simple code:

```
import threading, time

class reqthread(threading.Thread):    
    def run(self):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            time.sleep(1)
            print('.')

try:
    thread = reqthread()
    thread.start()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print('\n! Received keyboard interrupt, quitting threads.\n')
```

But when I run it, it prints

```
$ python prova.py
.
.
^C.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
Exception KeyboardInterrupt in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

In fact python thread ignore my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keyboard interrupt and doesn't print `Received Keyboard Interrupt`. Why? What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Related question: [linux - Cannot kill Python script with Ctrl-C - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815947/cannot-kill-python-script-with-ctrl-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try

```
try:
    thread = reqthread()
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(100)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print('Received keyboard interrupt, quitting threads.')
```

Without the call to `time.sleep`, the main process is jumping out of the `try...except` block too early, so the `KeyboardInterrupt` is not caught. My first thought was to use `thread.join`, but that seems to block the main process (ignoring KeyboardInterrupt) until the `thread` is finished.

`thread.daemon=True` causes the thread to terminate when the main process ends.

Comment: I believe a timeout on `join`, i.e. `while thread.isAlive: thread.join(5)` will also work to keep the main thread responsive to exceptions.

Comment: `thread.daemon = True` is actually not recommended because it doesn't allow the thread to clean up any resources left behind...

Comment: `daemon = True` doesn't kill the thread if there are any non-daemon threads running.
From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/threading.html#threading.daemon): 
_A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left._

So if you have any other threads running, it will terminate the main thread but all of your threads including daemons will stay alive.

Answer (score 15):

To summarize the changes recommended in [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788208/python-threading-ignores-keyboardinterrupt-exception#comment16625542_3788243) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788208/python-threading-ignores-keyboardinterrupt-exception#comment28203538_3788243), the following works well for me:

```
try:
  thread = reqthread()
  thread.start()
  while thread.isAlive(): 
    thread.join(1)  # not sure if there is an appreciable cost to this.
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
  print '\n! Received keyboard interrupt, quitting threads.\n'
  sys.exit()
```

Comment: Is calling "thread.join()" over and over in the "while thread.isAlive():" a good thing / does that matter?

Comment: Personally I don't know; might be worth trying to craft a benchmark if perf matters to you for that?

Comment: Be aware the exit() and sys.exit() are not the same. It is recommended to use sys.exit().

Comment: Thanks @DevPlayer ! Updated to reflect that. For the curious, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19747562/1048433 for an explanation

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It prints `Received keyboard interrupt, quitting threads.` but the thread keeps on printing dots.

Comment: isAlive is either no longer used or been renamed to "is_alive". Had the same like @fabian and threads kept on running.

Comment: it works on terminal but not in IDE

Answer (score 9):

Slight modification of Ubuntu's solution.

Removing `tread.daemon = True` as suggested by Eric and replacing the sleeping loop by signal.pause():

```
import signal

try:
  thread = reqthread()
  thread.start()
  signal.pause()  # instead of: while True: time.sleep(100)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
  print('Received keyboard interrupt, quitting threads.)
```

Comment: Nice - but unfortunately not supported on Windows

Answer (score 0):

My (hacky) solution is to monkey-patch `Thread.join()` like this:

```
def initThreadJoinHack():
  import threading, thread
  mainThread = threading.currentThread()
  assert isinstance(mainThread, threading._MainThread)
  mainThreadId = thread.get_ident()
  join_orig = threading.Thread.join
  def join_hacked(threadObj, timeout=None):
    """
    :type threadObj: threading.Thread
    :type timeout: float|None
    """
    if timeout is None and thread.get_ident() == mainThreadId:
      # This is a HACK for Thread.join() if we are in the main thread.
      # In that case, a Thread.join(timeout=None) would hang and even not respond to signals
      # because signals will get delivered to other threads and Python would forward
      # them for delayed handling to the main thread which hangs.
      # See CPython signalmodule.c.
      # Currently the best solution I can think of:
      while threadObj.isAlive():
        join_orig(threadObj, timeout=0.1)
    else:
      # In all other cases, we can use the original.
      join_orig(threadObj, timeout=timeout)
  threading.Thread.join = join_hacked
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `try ... except` in each thread and also a `signal.pause()` in *true* `main()` works for me.

Watch out for [import lock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354248/5896591) though. I am guessing this is why Python doesn't solve ctrl-C by default.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but I had this exact issue and required the Ctrl-C behavior to work on Docker (ubuntu 20.04) and on Windows. On windows specifically, the signal handling is done only onto the main thread, only when the thread is not in a wait state. This is both true for a try: except KeyboardInterrupt: and for a signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler) where either gets raised or called only when the main thread is out of a wait.

For instance if you change your code to the following and press Ctrl-C midway, you will see that the exception gets caught but only when reqThread actually terminates and therefore thread.join() returns.

```
import threading, time

class reqthread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            time.sleep(1)
            print('.')

try:
    thread = reqthread()
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print('\n! Received keyboard interrupt, quitting threads.\n')
```

However, an interesting thing is that when the main thread is running an asyncio loop, it will always catch a Ctrl-C on both Windows and Linux (at least on the docker Ubuntu image I am running).

the following piece of code demonstrates the behavior

```
import threading, time, signal, asyncio

localLoop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
syncShutdownEvent = threading.Event()

class reqthread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            time.sleep(1)
            print('.')
            if syncShutdownEvent.is_set():
                break

        print("reqthread stopped")

        done()

        return

def done():
    localLoop.call_soon_threadsafe(lambda: localLoop.stop())

def handler(signum, frame):
    signal.getsignal(signum)
    print(f'\n! Received signal {signal.Signals(signum).name}, quitting threads.\n')
    syncShutdownEvent.set()

def hookKeyboardInterruptSignals():
    for selectSignal in [x for x in signal.valid_signals() if isinstance(x, signal.Signals) and x.name in ('SIGINT', 'SIGBREAK')]:
        signal.signal(selectSignal.value, handler)

hookKeyboardInterruptSignals()
thread = reqthread()
thread.start()
asyncio.set_event_loop(localLoop)
localLoop.run_forever()
localLoop.close()
```

and will give you the same behavior on both Windows and Ubuntu

```
python scratch_14.py
.
.

! Received keyboard interrupt, quitting threads.

.
reqthread stopped
```

for my specific application where is need to use 1 thread running synchronous code and 1 thread running async code i actually use a total of three threads.

1. Main thread, running the Ctrl-C asyncio catcher
2. Synchronous thread
3. Asyncio loop thread

EDIT: fixed a typo that caused the first code block import statement to be interpreted as plain text instead of part of the code block