# Threaded Python application does not react on Ctrl+C

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a simple Python app that runs in two threads. One is SMTP server, the other is HTTP server. When I start it in terminal it does not react on Ctrl+C.
Here is the code:

```
import asyncore
import threading
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

from smtpd import SMTPServer


class MailHoleSMTP(SMTPServer):
    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        pass


def run_smtp():
    MailHoleSMTP(('localhost', 1025), None)
    asyncore.loop()


def run_http():
    handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(('localhost', 1080), handler)
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_http)
    smtp_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_smtp)
    http_thread.start()
    smtp_thread.start()

    http_thread.join()
    smtp_thread.join()
```

I suspect that something might be wrong with that `serve_forever()` call, maybe it does not play well with threads or something. What can I do to make it react on Ctrl+C?

**UPD:** It does not work (for both threads) even if I run only one of the two threads.

Comment: Do you see any output, possibly a traceback?

Comment: Nope, nothing, just ^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C :)

Comment: 3 threads, not 2. You're not counting the *main* thread, which is the one that catches the keyboard interrupt.

Comment: Related question: [python - threading ignores KeyboardInterrupt exception - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788208/threading-ignores-keyboardinterrupt-exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are two problems to address here.  First is that a `join`ed thread will not respond to any signals.  Fix that by looping to check for a signal once every second:

```
while http_thread.is_alive():
    http_thread.join(1)
#similar for smtp_thread
```

This will make your program respond to `KeyboardInterrupt` signals, but now you will notice that the whole thing doesn't shut down cleanly.  The reason: signals are not propagated to other threads, and the whole process is not allowed to shut down until your worker threads finish (because they are non-daemonic).  To fix, the simplest way is to just make them daemon threads:

```
http_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_http)
http_thread.daemon = True
smtp_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_smtp)
smtp_thread.daemon = True
...
```

Signaling is a pretty common topic in multithreaded applications, so you may want to [do more reading](http://snakesthatbite.blogspot.com/2010/09/cpython-threading-interrupting.html).

Comment: I've tried this but it looks that `thread.join()` blocks processing signals. But try to replace it with `while thread.is_alive(): time.sleep(1)` - works for me