# KeyboardInterrupt not working in Python to stop thread

Tags: python, multithreading, keyboardinterrupt

I want to capture and store the images from live streams using two threads. I want to stop the threads with Ctrl + C keyboard interrupt. I am calling a function from

> if **name** == "**main**":

but it is not working. I am using spyder with an anaconda environment. I also tried it using terminal but it is not working. Can anyone explain why and how it will work?

The code is as follow

```
class ImageGrabber(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, ID):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.ID=ID
    self.cam=cv2.VideoCapture(ID)
    self.fps = self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    self.w=self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    self.h=self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    (self.grabbed, self.frame) =self.cam.read()
    print(f"Camera Opened with fps {self.fps}, width = {self.w}, and height = {self.h}")
    plt.imshow(self.frame)
    plt.show()
    self.stopped = False
    
def run(self):
    global frames
    global exitProgram
    # print("Entered Grabbed Run ******:")
    while not self.stopped:
        if not self.grabbed or exitProgram is True:
            print("Exit Command reached")
            self.stop()
            self.cam.release()
        else:
            (self.grabbed, self.frame) =self.cam.read()
            frames.put(self.frame)
            
def stop(self):
    self.stopped = True

class ImageSaver(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self,grabber,codec):
     
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    global saveImages
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*codec)
    self.fName=self.getDateStamp() + '.avi'
    if saveImages is False:
        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter(self.fName, fourcc,grabber.fps ,(int(grabber.w),int(grabber.h)))
    
def getDateStamp(self):

    filedate = str(datetime.now())
    filedate = filedate[0:-7]
    filedate = filedate.replace(':', '_')
    filename = filedate 
#print(filename)

    return filename
def run(self):
    global frames
    global saveImages
    while True:
        # print("Entered Loop 1:")
        if(not frames.empty()):
            # print("Entered frame showing:")
            self.Currframe=frames.get()
            if saveImages is False:
                self.out.write(self.Currframe)
            else:
                self.imgName=self.getDateStamp() + '.tiff'
                cv2.imwrite(self.imgName,self.Currframe)
            print(f"Queue Size in writing = {frames.qsize()}")
            # print("Show Image")
        elif exitProgram is True:
            print("Exit Command Main reached")
            print(f"Final Queue Size at exit = {frames.qsize()}")
            break

def initStart(*args):

    argsList=sum(list(args),[])
    argsLen = len(argsList)

    if(argsLen==2):
        ID = int(argsList[0])
        codec = argsList[1]
    elif(argsLen==1):
        ID = int(argsList[0])
        codec = 'XVID'
    else:
        ID = 0
        codec = 'XVID'
    
    grabber = ImageGrabber(ID)
    saver = ImageSaver(grabber,codec)

    grabber.start()
    saver.start()
    e = threading.Event()
    # main.join()
    # grabber.join()

    print ('Press CTRL-C to interrupt')
    while grabber.isAlive():
        try: 
            time.sleep(1) #wait 1 second, then go back and ask if thread is still alive
            print ('Sleep...')
        except: #if ctrl-C is pressed within that second,
                              #catch the KeyboardInterrupt exception
                
            e.set() #set the flag that will kill the thread when it has finished
            exitProgram=True
            print ('Exiting...')
            grabber.join()
            saver.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    full_cmd_arguments = sys.argv
    # Keep all but the first. First contains the path of script or file
    argument_list = full_cmd_arguments[1:]
    initStart(argument_list)
```

If I change the program in such a way that keyboardInterrupt is called without any function then it works

```
grabber = ImageGrabber(0)
main = Main(grabber,'XVID')

grabber.start()
main.start()
e = threading.Event()
print ('Press CTRL-C to interrupt')
while grabber.isAlive():
    try: time.sleep(1) #wait 1 second, then go back and ask if thread is 
 
    except KeyboardInterrupt: #if ctrl-C is pressed within that second,
                          #catch the KeyboardInterrupt exception
            
        e.set() #set the flag that will kill the thread when it has finished
        exitProgram=True
        print ('Exiting...')
        grabber.join()
        main.join()
```

The above code is called directly as python script then it works. Any reason?

Any idea? how it can work?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788208/threading-ignores-keyboardinterrupt-exception?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
...
print ('Press CTRL-C to interrupt')
try: 
    while grabber.isAlive():
        time.sleep(1) #wait 1 second, then go back and ask if thread is 

except KeyboardInterrupt: #if ctrl-C is pressed within that second,
                      #catch the KeyboardInterrupt exception
    e.set() 
...
```

Try this way.
The reason why KeyboardInterrupt was not working is because the while loop was scoping the try except statement, so it would repeat it continuously even though you were pressing the KeyboardInterrupt.

Hope this helps!