# How to kill a child thread with Ctrl+C?

Tags: python, multithreading, kill, keyboardinterrupt

I would like to stop the execution of a process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Python. But I have read somewhere that `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions are only raised in the main thread. I have also read that the main thread is blocked while the child thread executes. So how can I kill the child thread?

For instance, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> has no effect with the following code:

```py
def main():
    try:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=f)
        thread.start()  # thread is totally blocking (e.g. while True)
        thread.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Ctrl+C pressed..."
        sys.exit(1)

def f():
    while True:
        pass  # do the actual work
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python

Comment: Your main thread isn't blocked because you start another thread. What would be the point of threads if that were true? It's because you're calling thread1.join(), which DOES block until thread1 is done.

Comment: Related question: [multithreading - Interruptible thread join in Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631441/interruptible-thread-join-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem there is that you are using `thread1.join()`, which will cause your program to wait until that thread finishes to continue.

The signals will always be caught by the main process, because it's the one that receives the signals, it's the process that has threads.

Doing it as you show, you are basically running a 'normal' application, without thread features, as you start 1 thread and wait until it finishes to continue.

Comment: But the main thread still receives exit signal right? so why doesn't it send the signal to its child and both exits?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to have main thread to receive the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal while joining, it can be done by adding timeout to `join()` call.

The following seems to be working (don't forget to add `daemon=True` if you want main to actually end):

```
thread1.start()
while True:
    thread1.join(600)
    if not thread1.isAlive():
        break
```

Comment: The value passed to thread.join is in seconds, so this will still block ctr-c for up to 10 minutes.  Passing in a value of '1' or so is much more responsive.

Answer (score 8):

`KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions are raised only in the main thread of each process. But the method `Thread.join` blocks the calling thread, *including* `KeyboardInterrupt` *exceptions*. That is why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> seems to have no effect.

A simple solution to your problem is to make the method `Thread.join` time out to unblock `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions, and make the child thread [daemonic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) to let the parent thread kill it at exit (non-daemonic child threads are not killed but joined by their parent at exit):

```py
def main():
    try:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=f)
        thread.daemon = True  # let the parent kill the child thread at exit
        thread.start()
        while thread.is_alive():
            thread.join(1)  # time out not to block KeyboardInterrupt
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Ctrl+C pressed..."
        sys.exit(1)

def f():
    while True:
        pass  # do the actual work
```

A better solution if you control the code of the child thread is to notify the child thread to exit gracefully (instead of abruptly like with the simple solution), for instance using a `threading.Event`:

```py
def main():
    try:
        event = threading.Event()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(event,))
        thread.start()
        event.wait()  # wait without blocking KeyboardInterrupt
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Ctrl+C pressed..."
        event.set()  # notify the child thread to exit
        sys.exit(1)

def f(event):
    while not event.is_set():
        pass  # do the actual work
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me: using Python 3.8.x.  A `KeyboardInterrupt` doesn't seem to be catchable as far as I can work out.  In other code I'm getting a thing saying "exception was ignored" when a keyboard interrupt occurs.

Comment: @mikerodent Have you tried the two examples in this answer?

Comment: Going to delete my comment... am slowly learning how these things work. My solution to graceful shutdown and responsiveness to Ctrl-C (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66949660/595305): from my experiments it seems that a `while True:` loop on the main thread is necessary...

Comment: @Maggyero is this what a signalling is?