# Why doesn't daemon thread die when its environment is destroyed?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a Python script which starts a thread from another thread. This is a learning exercise to actually realise the ability to [kill a python thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python), which does have a use in an application that I am writing. Ignoring the red herring, thread `FirstThread` starts thread `SecondThread` which for our purposes is caught in a loop and has no resources to release. Consider:

```
import threading
import time


class FirstThread (threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        b = SecondThread()
        b.daemon = True
        b.start()
        time.sleep(3)
        print("FirstThread going away!")
        return True


class SecondThread (threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("SecondThread")


a = FirstThread()
a.daemon = True
a.start()


print("Waiting 5 seconds.")
time.sleep(5)
print("Done waiting")
```

Although `FirstThread` does print "FirstThread going away!" after 3 seconds as expected, `SecondThread` continues to print "SecondThread" to stdout. I expected `SecondThread` to be destroyed with `FirstThread` is destroyed as it is [a daemon thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815947/cannot-kill-python-script-with-ctrl-c). So why does `SecondThread` continue to exist even though its environment (FirstThread) has been destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads are not hierarchical in nature.  AFAIK, a thread maintains a closure on the environment that it was created in but that is it.  All threads are owned by a *process*.  A `daemon` thread is simply a thread that will not be joined before the application exits.  In short, there is no tie between `FirstThread` and `SecondThread` in your example.