# Python printing nothing?

Tags: python, multithreading, printing

just following a tutorial and have as far as I know copied it exactly yet mine won't print anything out at all, it should obviously print from each function constantly but I don't seem to be getting anything back, not sure why ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import thread
import time
import random

def runOften(threadName, sleepTime):
    while 1 < 2:
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        print "%s" %(threadName)

def runLessOften(threadName, sleepTime):
    while 1 < 2:
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        print "%s" %(threadName)

def runRandomly(threadName, sleepTime):
    while 1 < 2:
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        print "%s" %(threadName)

try:
    thread.start_new_thread(runOften, ("Often Runs", 2))
    thread.start_new_thread(runLessOften, ("Less Often Runs!", 2))
    thread.start_new_thread(runRandomly, ("Fast and random", random.random()))

except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better solution is to use the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module, which provides the [`Thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) class - an object-oriented interface to threads.

This way, we can easily [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) the three running threads (wait for them to finish).

Adapting your example:

```
import threading
import time
import random

keep_running = True

def runOften(threadName, sleepTime):
    while keep_running:
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        print "%s" %(threadName)

def runLessOften(threadName, sleepTime):
    while keep_running:
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        print "%s" %(threadName)

def runRandomly(threadName, sleepTime):
    while keep_running:
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        print "%s" %(threadName)


def main():
    global keep_running

    # Create the threads
    threads = []
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=runOften, args=("Often Runs", 2)))
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=runLessOften, args=("Less Often Runs!", 2)))
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=runRandomly, args=("Fast and random", random.random())))

    # Start the threads
    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    # Wait for all of the threads to finish.
    # Note: KeyboardInterrupt will not be raised inside of a call to join()
    #       with no timeout. So we set an arbitrarily large timeout, which
    #       (for whatever reason) allows KeyboardInterrupt to be raised.
    while threads:
        for t in list(threads):          # Iterate over a copy
            try:
                t.join(1000)             # Arbitrary timeout value
                if not t.isAlive():      # If thread finished (join didn't time-out),
                    threads.remove(t)    # We'll no longer join() on it
            except KeyboardInterrupt:    # If we get a Ctrl+C,
                keep_running = False     # Set global flag, telling threads to stop looping

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Why is this *better* than (even though it's aesthetically inferior to) `while True: pass` ? Because that will make the CPU *busy-wait* for the Ctrl+C, robbing valuable execution time from the other threads.  This solution will instead allow the other threads to run, only waking up when Ctrl+C is pressed.

Other questions on handling Ctrl+C with threads:

- [Terminate a multi-thread python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635080/terminate-a-multi-thread-python-program)
- [Python program with thread can't catch CTRL+C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652446/python-program-with-thread-cant-catch-ctrlc)
- [Python - Can't kill main thread with KeyboardInterrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991033/python-cant-kill-main-thread-with-keyboardinterrupt)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11148458/119527), which independently came up with the same solution as I did.

I should also point out that `runRandomly` doesn't do what its name implies; instead, it will always sleep the same amount of time every iteration. That amount is randomly decided once when the program starts.

Comment: +1 for the use of ``threading.Thread`` (*obviously*). But I'm not sure I like your approach here for the simple reason that it's **hard** to terminate the program without killing it or using ``^\`` :)

Comment: @JamesMills Still trying to figure out how to handle that in an elegant fashion. It's interesting to note that it seems `KeyboardInterrupt` won't be raised from inside of a call to `.join()`.

Comment: I'm not sure there is to be honest. (*Threads suck*). You could do it in an elegant way if you used ``circuits`` :) You'd have to start each component as threads (*a stupid idea really*) but at least the system would terminate nicely.

Comment: @JamesMills Finally, got a solution that works, although "elegant" would probably *not* be the word for it.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to remove the element from a list when iterating. And join a thread not alive will not block you.

Comment: @WKPlus Indeed. And if you look closely at my code, you'll see that I am iterating over *a copy* of the list, and removing the item from *the original* list.

Comment: A similarly contrived example of the OP's program behaviour using circuits: http://codepad.org/cV7HpHpv -- Without any further specifics form the OP the behaviour of this contrived program is all about timers and events :)

Comment: Awesome thanks for this solution! Interesting that the tutorial I was following has it exactly like I did yet his seemed to work? He was using Windows and I am using Linux, but wouldn't think that should change anything.

Answer (score 6):

Put this at the end of your code:

```
while True:
    pass
```

Your program termintes prematurely.

You have nothing in your "MainThread". You spawn 3 threads but do nothing in the so-called "main program". So Python terminates normally.

With the above added to the end I get the following output:

```
$ python foo.py
Fast and random
Fast and random
Fast and random
Often Runs
 Less Often Runs!
Fast and random
Fast and random
Fast and random
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 30, in <module>
    while True:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to present here a different implementation of the behaviour of the code the OP presented using the [circuits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/circuits) application framework because:

- It's elegant
- It works
- It terminates with `^C`
- It doesn't use threads
- It illustrates the same behaviour.

The behaviour of this program is basically all about timers and events.

Running this produces:

```
$ python foo.py 
Run Less Often
Run Often
Run Randomly
Run Less Often
Run Less Often
Run Often
```

Code: http://codepad.org/cV7HpHpv

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from random import randint


from circuits import Component, Event, Timer


class App(Component):

    def init(self):
        Timer(5, Event.create("run_often"), persist=True).register(self)
        Timer(3, Event.create("run_less_often"), persist=True).register(self)
        Timer(randint(1, 10), Event.create("run_randomly")).register(self)

    def run_often(self):
        print "Run Often"

    def run_less_often(self):
        print "Run Less Often"

    def run_randomly(self):
        print "Run Randomly"

        Timer(randint(1, 10), Event.create("run_randomly")).register(self)


App().run()
```

Comment: Interesting, does this run the same as using threading? It didn't run for me :(

Comment: You'll want to firstly: ``pip install circuits==3.0.0.dev`` and no it doesn't use threads. it's completely event-driven and asynchronous.