# joining a thread with any argument causes it to recognize keyboard interrupts

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, blocking, interrupt-handling

As has been [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/631441/403875) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17991033/403875) [times](http://www.regexprn.com/2010/05/killing-multithreaded-python-programs.html), calling Thread.join() with no argument will wait until the thread finishes before throwing a KeyboardInterrupt.
What I find curious is that if you provide any argument at all, then join will exit immediately when interrupted (rather than waiting for the next timeout).  Why is this?

```
# test.py

import threading

x = threading.Event()
def waitForever():
    x.wait()

t = threading.Thread(target = waitForever)
t.start()

try:
    t.join(float('inf'))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    x.set()
    print "Killed"
```

---

```
$ python test.py 
^CKilled
$
```

Comment: Didn't you get `OverflowError: timeout value is too large`?