# why -it flag is needed to enable Ctrl + C or Ctrl + D to get out of a running container?

Tags: linux, docker

below is a very simple image below, say the generated image is simpleweb

```
FROM node:14-alpine

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and if I run below three commands:

1. `docker run simpleweb`
2. `docker run -i simpleweb`
3. `docker run -t simpleweb`

I got the following outout to my terminal

```
> @ start /
> node index.js

Listening on port 8080
```

and I press Ctrl + C or Ctrl + D, I couldn't get out of the container.

so I have to run

4. `docker run -it simpleweb`

to be able to press Ctrl + C or Ctrl + D to get out of the container

my question is, why I couldn't get out of container in the first three commands?

Comment: Does [Docker not responding to CTRL+C in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350335/docker-not-responding-to-ctrlc-in-terminal) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidMaze no, from what I know, docker client will send a SGKILL signal  10 seconds after  Ctrl + C, but in my case, nothing happen, and the post doesn't explain why `docker run -it` works

Answer (score 3):

If you just run `docker run simpleweb` then the resulting container is completely isolated from the terminal that it was launched in. It will not respond to any signals (both `Ctrl-C` and `Ctrl-D` send signals to a running process).

By adding the `-it` flags you make the container responsive.

- `-i` (or `--interactive`) — leaves the container connected to `stdin`
- `-t` (or `--tty`) — allocates a pseudo-terminal

The combination of these flags leaves the container attached to a pseudo-terminal, so that anything typed into the console is relayed to the running container.