# Why is the main thread of my multithreaded application unresponsive to Ctrl+C?

Tags: python, windows

I have written a multithreaded application to watch and respond to changes in given list of files. I have a `Watch`  class which gets the file size and sets it to `size` variable upon first call. Then, after a few seconds it again gets the size of the file and compares it with with the previous  size and, if changed, sets `size` to the current size of the file. Furthermore there is a `WatchWorker` class which is a subclass of `threading.Thread`. The `WatchWorker` which makes use of `Watch` class to 'watch ' a given file.

Now here is the real problem : 
The code I have written is working and notifies the user when a change is detected. But there is no response when I try to quit from the application using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I'm on Windows.

Code:

```
import time
import threading
import os

class Watch(object):
    def __init__(self, path, time=5):
        self.path = path
        self.time = time
        self.size = os.stat(path).st_size



    def loop(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(self.time)
            size = os.stat(self.path).st_size
            if size != self.size:
                self.size = size
                print "Change detected in file {}".format(self.path)



class Watch_Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Watch_Worker, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.path = path


    def run(self):
        super(Watch_Worker, self).run()
        Watch(self.path).loop()

def main(*args):
    for i in args:
        thrd = Watch_Worker(path=i)
        thrd.start()
        print 'Watching ' + i
        print "From main thread"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('blah.js', 'cs.c', 'ab.rb')
```

**Edit**

Modified code to compare the values produced `os.stat('somefile.ext').st_size)`.

Comment: This is not uncommon you should Google for this.  If you want an answer you need to provide a minimum working example (code).

Comment: Reading all the files periodically is VERY resource consuming. I think you should check the modification date first, or use some kind of os specific file system watcher

Comment: @hege_hegedus I'm actually trying to make something like grunt-watch,  and I wanted a cross platform solution too. However I will update my code to check modification time of the file soon. Thanks :)

Comment: btw do you mean Ctrl+C

Comment: @PyNEwbie But that's not related to this question in anyway!

Comment: Sorry this is the one I meant to grab http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815947/cannot-kill-python-script-with-ctrl-c

Comment: Please include the code inside of the question itself, not as an external link (which is vulnerable to link rot). There are much better ways than reading a file every N seconds for checking for changes.

Comment: You let the main thread exit, so CPython's `Py_Finalize` function calls `threading._MainThread._exitfunc`, which does a blocking `join` on each thread. The main thread can't respond to the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception while blocked. You should add a loop in `main` to `join` each thread with a timeout. Use a try /except to handle `KeyboardInterrupt` to set a value that tells all of your `Watch_Worker` threads to exit.

Comment: As a quick hack you can restore the default `SIGINT` handler that exits the process: `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)`.

Comment: Note that Windows doesn't actually have signals. The C runtime sets a console control handler that in turn calls the `SIGINT` and `SIGBREAK` handlers for console Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break events. If you run this as a non-console program via pythonw.exe, there's no way to signal the process with `SIGINT`. So you really do need to manage your thread shutdown properly without relying on Ctrl+C.

Comment: The code shown does not work at all. Since `Watch.loop()` is never called by anything, there will be no output. There are other errors, this is the most glaring. Make sure what you post actually is what you are running.

Comment: @msw What are the errors yoj came across?

Comment: OMG are you serious? I can't speak for windows, but the code shown exits immediately after the last `thrd.start()` because you never join the running threads. However I think the first defect I mentioned (never calling any code that does any work) is more than enough to call this a broken program. So again, what code are you actually running?

Comment: @msw, these are not `daemon` threads. The interpreter doesn't let the main thread finalize and exit until each thread is joined. That's not specific to Windows, nor is Ctrl+C not working specific to Windows. The main thread is blocked while waiting on a thread, so the interpreter never gets to evaluate the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception set by Python's default `SIGINT` handler. If the system's default handler is restored, Ctrl+C will kill the process.

Comment: I have fixed it and is well and working.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I'm new to Stack Overflow. Again,  Thanks you all for your feedback.

Comment: @eryksun the OP's own answer below  and the interpreter disagree with you. Did you, say, run, the code in question, or did you just decide to invent the content of your comment? Code is kinda annoyingly deterministic in that way.

Comment: @msw, of course I ran the code from the question on both Linux and Windows. The OP is not setting `daemon=True` in the above code. He or she appears to have discovered that after I told you that "these are not `daemon` threads". And the solution of making them daemon threads is still not much better than disabling Python's `SIGINT` handler. It's a dirty solution. The OP should set a value for the threads to exit normally and let the interpreter `join` them.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem of the main thread being prevented from exiting by setting `self.daemon = True`. The main thread does not wait for the threads to exit. This is solved by adding a infinite `while` loop with`time.sleep(5)` to the end of `main` function. Here is the code:

```
class Watch_Worker(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, path, time=2,  *args, **kwargs):
            super(Watch_Worker, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.path = path
            self.time = time
            self.size = os.stat(path).st_size
            self.daemon = True


        def run(self):
            super(Watch_Worker, self).run()
            while True:
                time.sleep(self.time)
                size = os.stat(self.path).st_size
                if size != self.size:
                    self.size = size
                    print "Change detected in file {}".format(self.path)

    def main(*args):
        for i in args:
            thrd = Watch_Worker(path=i)
            thrd.start()
            print 'Watching ' + i
         while True:
             time.sleep(5)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main('blah.js', 'cs.c', 'ab.rb')
```