# Python SIGINT not caught

Tags: python, multithreading, sigint

I don't manage to understand why my SIGINT is never caught by the piece of code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import signal

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.running = True

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            for i in range(500):
                col = i**i
                print col
                sleep(0.01)

global threads
threads = []

for w in range(150):
    threads.append(MyThread())

def stop(s, f):
    for t in threads:
        t.stop()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop)

for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

To clean this code I would prefer to try/except the `join()` and closing all threads in case of exception, would that work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interruptible thread join in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631441/interruptible-thread-join-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the problems with multithreading in python is that `join()` more or less disables signals.

This is because the signal can only be delivered to the main thread, but the main thread is already busy with performing the `join()` and the join is not interruptible.

You can deduce this from the documentation of the `signal` module

> Some care must be taken if both signals and threads are used in the same program. The fundamental thing to remember in using signals and threads simultaneously is: always perform signal() operations in the main thread of execution. Any thread can perform an alarm(), getsignal(), pause(), setitimer() or getitimer(); only the main thread can set a new signal handler, and **the main thread will be the only one to receive signals** (this is enforced by the Python signal module, even if the underlying thread implementation supports sending signals to individual threads). This means that signals can’t be used as a means of inter-thread communication. Use locks instead.

You can work your way around it, by busy-looping over the join operation:

```
for t in threads:
    while t.isAlive():
        t.join(timeout=1)
```

This is, however, none to efficient:

> The workaround of calling join() with a timeout has a drawback:
>   Python's threading wait routine polls 20 times a second when
>   given any timeout.  All this polling can mean lots of CPU
>   interrupts/wakeups on an otherwise idle laptop and drain the
>   battery faster.

Some more details are provided here:

[Python program with thread can't catch CTRL+C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652446/python-program-with-thread-cant-catch-ctrlc)

Bug reports for this problem with a discussion of the underlying issue can be found here:

https://bugs.python.org/issue1167930

https://bugs.python.org/issue1171023